# Does Lunar client (for Minecraft) have a 1.14 version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

### How do I join in 1.14 from Lunar?

When I joined a hypixel game of build battle, I saw that the lobby was in 1.14 (I can't use blocks from later versions). I want to try and join in 1.14 from lunar, but I can't seem to switch to that version. Is there a way to switch to 1.14 in Lunar client?

[image: Picture of lunar client versions.]

Comment: This is not a *technical* but a practical problem, right?

Comment: @Joachim It's both. I don't need it but it is a technical problem.

Comment: @Joachim I agree with you, this is definitely not a technical problem (even if the asker declares it as one). There is nothing that is *explicitly broken* here, so this shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per the community consensus at the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10568/4797) and [What exactly is technical support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797) only *crash* issues and other technical issues related to *running* modded Minecraft are off-topic. Outside of those, modded Minecraft issues are on-topic.

Comment: Thanks @galacticninja

Comment: 1.13 marked a huge shift in file format of Minecraft data. Mods and other "fan projects" took a long, long time to catch up with the changes - and often (usually?) authors playing catch-up with new releases got them stable and working by the time 1.15 was out, and so they didn't bother adapting them to obsolete versions. Especially that 1.14 was painfully buggy and unstable; "1.15 Bugs&Bees" only added bees - the Bugs in the title was about the massive spree of fixing 1.14 bugs.

Comment: Thanks, @SF. That is intresting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, no it does not.
This is a direct quote from the website:

> Lunar Client also offers the most popular versions of Minecraft such as 1.7, 1.8, 1.12, 1.16, 1.17 and 1.18 directly in our launcher.

As shown there is no mention of 1.14 anywhere on the website.

Comment: So, there is no way to add it again? I think that it was at one point in the client when 1.14 first came out.

Comment: @BlueRobin they removed support for 1.14 when 1.17 came out if I remember correctly (might have been when 1.18 came out)

Comment: @BlueRobin you can join Build Battle games with newer blocks from version 1.14+, so 1.16 will work and you will be able to join games with 1.14 blocks (but not blocks from 1.16, so you still get the annoyance of blocks in your inventory you can't use)

Comment: @Esther I know I can use later versions but I just wanted to figure out how to join in 1.14 to not have that minor annoyance of using a block from a later version.